# Understand a proof in Folland

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $f\in L^+$, then $f=0$ $\mu$-a.e. if and only if $\int f=0.$

I have a question for the converse case.

> Conversely, suppose $\int f=0$ Then consider the set $E=\{x: f(x)>0\}=\bigcup \{x:f(x)>\dfrac{1}{n}\}$. Suppose that $f \neq 0$ $\mu$-a.e. then there exists $n$ such that $\mu(E_n)>0$ and $f> \dfrac{1}{n}\chi_{E_n}\implies \int f >\dfrac{1}{n}\mu(E_n)>0$.

I dont quite understand why we need to further decompose $E$ into unions of $\{x:f(x)>\dfrac{1}{n}\}$. Wouldnt I get the same result, if I assume $f$ is not 0 a.e. and $\mu(E)>0$ then $f>0$ on $E$ and $\int f \geq \int_E f=\sup\{\int_E \phi : 0\leq \phi \leq f\}>0$ where $\phi$ is simple and also because $\int_E \phi =\sum^k a_i \mu(F_i\cap E)>0$?

Comment: But why is this supremum positive? Can you prove there is a specific simple function for which the integral on $E$ is positive?

Comment: @Mark I see! thanks for pointing that out.